# JBoss Developer Studio (Eclipse) Data Source Explorer - Disconnect HSQL still locked

Tags: eclipse, jpa, jboss, hsqldb

I have a database connection to HSQL in Eclipse via the Data Source Explorer (DSE).  I can browse the existing HSQL database just fine, and then I disconnect and start a web app that uses the same database.  After disconnecting, my web app won't start unless I restart Eclipse because it says the HSQL database is locked.

If I start Eclipse and run my web app then it works fine.

What it looks like is that when I disconnect hte Eclipse DSE it does not actually release the lock properly.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who is still looking for an answer:

HSQLDB lock file is not released from Eclipse Data source explorer when you disconnect, when you connect to file based URL. To release the lock, execute SHUTDOWN command on the DB (e.g. by opening SQL Scrapbook against the connection and executing SHUTDOWN as an SQL statement) and then disconnect. Also, this command could even be executed by starting a new session from the data source explorer itself, if you have disconnected before executing the shutdown command.